# Efficient Filtering of Lists in a Dictionary of Lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm working with some reasonably large datasets (500,000 datapoints with 30 variables each) and would like to find the most efficient methods for filtering them.

For compatibility with existing code the data is structured as a dictionary of lists but can't be converted (e.g. to pandas DataFrame) and has to be filtered in situ.

Working example:

```
data = {'Param0':['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6'],
        'Param1':['A','A','A','B','B','C'],
        'Param2': [100,200,150,80,90,50],
        'Param3': [20,60,40,30,30,5]}

# Param0 keys to keep
keep = ['x2', 'x4']

filtered = {k: [x for i, x in enumerate(v) if data['Param0'][i] in keep] for k, v in data.items()}
```

The result `filtered` gives the desired output, but this is very slow at scale.

Are there any quicker ways of doing this?

Comment: Reorganize your data and use `Param0` values as keys, it is the correct way.

Comment: Use Numpy ( vectorized operation), for filtering efficiently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do:

```py
keep_idx = [i for i, v in enumerate(data['Param0']) if v in keep]
filtered = {k: [v[i] for i in keep_idx] for k, v in data.items()}
```

Timing

```py
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

# Solution in question
def test_1(data, keep):
    return {
        k: [x for i, x in enumerate(v) if data['Param0'][i] in keep]
        for k, v in data.items()
    }

# First solution from @I'mahdi
def test_2(data, keep):
    keep_idx = [i for i, v in enumerate(data['Param0']) if v in keep]
    return {
        k: [val for i, val in enumerate(v) if i in keep_idx]
        for k, v in data.items()
    }

# Second solution from @I'mahdi
def test_3(data, keep):
    keep_idx = [i for i, v in enumerate(data['Param0']) if v in keep]
    return {k: list(np.asarray(v)[keep_idx]) for k, v in data.items()}

# Solution in this answer
def test_4(data, keep):
    keep_idx = [i for i, v in enumerate(data['Param0']) if v in keep]
    return {k: [v[i] for i in keep_idx] for k, v in data.items()}


data = {f"Param{i}": list(range(10_000)) for i in range(20)}
keep = list(range(0, 10_000, 100))

print(test_1(data, keep) == test_2(data, keep))
print(test_2(data, keep) == test_3(data, keep))
print(test_3(data, keep) == test_4(data, keep))

for i in range(1, 5):
    t = timeit(f"test_{i}(data, keep)", globals=globals(), number=10)
    print(f"Solution {i}: {t:.3f}")
```

results in something like:

```
Solution 1: 4.571
Solution 2: 4.220
Solution 3: 0.298
Solution 4: 0.219
```

Comment: Many thanks to yourself and @I'mahdi. I'd created a lookup index and filtering similar to Solution 1, but solution 4 is a really substantial improvement and much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `look_up_idx` first might be a better idea:

```
look_up_idx = [idx for idx, v in enumerate(data['Param0']) if v in keep]
filtered = {k: [v[idx] for idx in look_up_idx] for k, v in data.items()}
print(filtered)
```

Or plus using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

look_up_idx = [idx for idx, v in enumerate(data['Param0']) if v in keep]
filtered = {k: list(np.asarray(v)[look_up_idx]) for k, v in data.items()}
```

---

```
{'Param0': ['x2', 'x4'],
 'Param1': ['A', 'B'],
 'Param2': [200, 80],
 'Param3': [60, 30]}
```